# [foxy] Is there any equivalent of matrix transformations for tf2 in ros 2?

Tags: ros, python, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In Ros1 you could use functions from these imports:

```
from tf_matrix_ops import tf_to_matrix, matrix_to_tf 
from tf.transformations import decompose_matrix
```

where you could transform tf to matrix then multiply them, take the inverse or extract informations from them.

I have a code sample that do the following and I would like to know if it is possible to do the same with ros2 and tf 2:

```
 m1 = tf_to_matrix(tf1)  
 m2 = tf_to_matrix(tf2)
 delta = np.matmul(m1, np.linalg.inv(m2)) 
 scale, shear, angles, t, perspective = decompose_matrix(delta)
```

I think the tf_matrix_ops and tf.transformations are not available in ros2 (or at least i did not find them) so maybe there is a new way to do this kind of thing ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365958/%5Bfoxy%5D-is-there-any-equivalent-of-matrix-transformations-for-tf2-in-ros-2-?/) by [Alrevan](https://answers.ros.org/users/48145/alrevan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2020-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An update on this question:

I realised that "tf_matrix_ops is actually" a homemade package I wrote some time ago...
For the case of "transformations.py" it is reallsy starightforward to convert it to ROS 2 as it is bascically a mathematic operation package.

After this one can easily write "tf_to_matrix" and "matrix_to_tf" helper functions using euler_from_quaternion, quaternion_from_euler, compose_matrix and decompose_matrix from transformations.py.

---

Originally posted by [Alrevan](https://answers.ros.org/users/48145/alrevan/) with karma: 126 on 2020-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0